# Appending rows to empty Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I read on this site [this.pointer.com](https://thispointer.com/pandas-how-to-create-an-empty-dataframe-and-append-rows-columns-to-it-in-python/) that you should append a dictionary to an empty dataframe like so

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['count', 'name'])

f = open("fbnames.txt", "r")
count = 0
save_every = 1

for line in f:
    count += 1
    split = line.split()
    df.append({'count':split[0], 'name':split[1].capitalize()}, ignore_index=True)
    print(df)

df.to_csv("fbnames.csv")
```

But the 'print(df)' just prints an empty dataframe everytime. What's going on? I'm just trying to read a txt file line by line then turn the line into a pandas dataframe row and append it.

Answer (score 2):

Because [`DataFrame.append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) not working inplace, is necessary assign output back:

```
df = df.append({'count':split[0], 'name':split[1].capitalize()}, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: @user8714896 - in pure python working `append` inplace, in pandas not.